# ChromeDriver Laravel Dusk Set Download File Path

Tags: php, laravel, selenium-chromedriver, laravel-dusk

Hi all wanted to ask how to set chromeDriver options default path to a specific directory so that if one downloads file using laravel dusk headless driver, files downloads to the directory.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$this->browse(function (Browser $browser) {
    $url = $browser->driver->getCommandExecutor()->getAddressOfRemoteServer();
    $uri = '/session/' . $browser->driver->getSessionID() . '/chromium/send_command';
    $body = [
        'cmd' => 'Page.setDownloadBehavior',
        'params' => ['behavior' => 'allow', 'downloadPath' => '/your/download/path']
    ];
    (new \GuzzleHttp\Client())->post($url . $uri, ['body' => json_encode($body)]);

    $browser->visit('/');
});
```

Replace `/your/download/path` with the actual path.

This example requires the [`guzzlehttp/guzzle`](https://packagist.org/packages/guzzlehttp/guzzle) package to execute the POST request.

There are other solutions without external dependencies:
[How do I send a POST request with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5647461/how-do-i-send-a-post-request-with-php)

Comment: the code you gave is working fine when site directly download the file. But when the link to download file uses another tab it doesn't work. Is there any other possibility or param to define and download the file. Thanks.

Comment: Manually opening the file url works for me: `$browser->visit($browser->element('a')->getAttribute('href'));`